# How to simulate a button click in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am currently learning selenium. I tried to simulate button click of a csv file from url "https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp/#worldCountries".

I did:

```
Right click the csv icon
Inspect and copy the full xpath
```

Then I used following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp'
driver.get(url)

xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]'

btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
btn.click()

# df = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/data.csv'))
# print(df.head())
# driver.close()
```

## Errro

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a>...</a> is not clickable at point (1070, 879). Other element would receive the click: <div id="google_ads_iframe_/15184186/worldpopulationreview_adhesion_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64)
```

## Attempts

I tried multiple attempts with different xpaths, but to no avail. How to simulate button click for this particular website?

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? What did it say? Did you look at the page when the click was attempted? What did you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes selenium is not able to click on an element if something is in the way. In that case you can use javascript. But first I would wait for the element to be clickable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp'
driver.get(url)

xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]'

# btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@download='csvData.csv']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
# btn.click()

# df = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/data.csv'))
# print(df.head())
# driver.close()
```

Comment: It worked, but json is downloaded instead of csv. how to download csv ?

Comment: @MilkyWay001 I updated the xpath from the one you provided to target the csv.

Answer (score 2):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector.

```
driver.get("https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[download='csvData.csv']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```